# In MSYS2 env, CTest fail with 0xc0000135 error when I use std::string

Tags: c++, cmake, std, msys2, ctest

Sorry, actually I don't know if this is a CMake, MSYS2 or g++ problem ?
I created a simple CMake project as below:

```
Hello/
|__build/
|__CMakeLists.txt
|__lib/
     |__CMakeLists.txt
     |__foo.cpp
     |__foo.h
     |__tests/
          |__CMakeLists.txt
          |__test0.cpp
```

The foo.cpp and foo.h define a simple function foo(), and test0.cpp call foo(), that's it.

This project run OK in MSYS2/mingw64 (and MSYS2/clang64) env, if foo() doesn't declare
a std::string.  But if I declare a std::string in foo(), CTest will fail with
0xc0000135 error.  What I means is if foo() looks like this

```
int foo(int in) {
    printf("HELLO %d\n", in);
    return in;
}
```

everything is OK.  But

```
int foo(int in) {
    str::string msg = "HELLO";
    printf("HELLO %d\n", in);
    return in;
}
```

the ctest will fail with the following error message !!!

```
    > ctest
    Test project D:/Hello/build
        Start 1: test0
    1/1 Test #1: test0 ............................Exit code 0xc0000135
    ***Exception:   0.02 sec

    0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1
    Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec
    The following tests FAILED:
              1 - test0 (Exit code 0xc0000135
    )
    Errors while running CTest
    Output from these tests are in: D:/KC/msys64/home/user/hello-07.std/build/Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log
```

Any suggestion is apreciated.
Thanks a lot.

The sources and CMakeLists.txt are listed below:
The env is Win11 + MSYS2 (msys2-x86_64-20230318.exe)
I tested them on mingw64 and clang64, both have the same behavior.

## Hello/CMakeLists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    project(Hello)

    enable_testing()
    include(CTest)

    subdirs(lib)
```

## Hello/lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D_WINDLL")

    add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp foo.h)
    target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE .)
    subdirs(tests)
```

## Hello/lib/tests/CMakeLists.txt

```
    add_executable(test0 test0.cpp)
    target_include_directories(test0 PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
    target_link_libraries(test0 foo)

    add_test(NAME test0 COMMAND test0)
    if (WIN32)
        set_tests_properties(test0 PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}\\..;$ENV{PATH}" )
    endif()
```

## Hello/lib/foo.h

```
    #ifndef __FOO_H
    #define __FOO_H

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef _WINDLL
    #define API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    #else
    #define API
    #endif

    API int foo(int in);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif

    #endif /* __FOO_H */
```

## Hello/lib/foo.cpp

```
    #include <foo.h>

    API int foo(int i)
    {
        // std::string msg = "HELLO"; // uncomment this will cause strange error !!
        printf("hello %d\n", i);
        return i;
    }
```

## Hello/lib/tests/test0.cpp

```
    #include <foo.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        return foo(0);
    }
```

Except MSYS2/mingw64 and MSYS2/clang64 env in Win11, I also the same code in CentOS 7x and Rocky 9x.  Under Linux, everything is OK.  The ctest will PASS.

Comment: Instead of going through all of these tests, you should create a simple application using g++ that consists of only those 4 lines in `main`, and a simple `g++` command line to build and run the application.  If you can't get that application to build and run, then introducing other things like cmake on top of it isn't going to work either.

Comment: at a guess the standard library dlls arent on your path

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. As already said you need to eliminate all the other components. (g++, ctest, CMake etc,) one by one, to see which one is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Which file has #include <string> in?

Comment: Sorry, it's in foo.cpp

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please don't modify `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly (with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D_WINDLL")`). Instead use [`target_compile_definition`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html). Like `target_compile_definition(foo PRIVATE _WINDLL)`

Comment: Try doing what PaulMcKenzie said. Normally those issues are caused by having conflicting DLLs in PATH (are you running the app from the MSYS2 shell, which should have a clean PATH, or from somewhere else?).

Comment: The PATH is OK, it includes /mingw64/bin/ and libstdc++-6.dll should be found by default.  In fact, running test0.exe directly from MSYS2 shell is OK (if I add .. to PATH for libfoo.dll).  The problem only happen when test0.exe was invoked by CTest.

Comment: I best guess, CTest might confuse with Windows' PATH (d:\\msys64\\mingw64\\...) and UNIX's PATH (/d/msys64/mingw64/...), but I don't know how to fix this ...

Comment: I wouldn't use backslashes in paths in cmake unless you absolutely have to. Windows should be able to deal with slashes instead of backslashes. My recommendation would be to replace the command of the test with a cmake script simply outputting the current value of the `PATH` environment variable (`add_test(... COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P myscript.cmake)`) which should provide you with additional info that should help with debugging the issue. [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html) may help with path conversions, if necessary

Comment: ldd lib/test0.exe will display the DLL used.
ctest -VV will display the PATH env.  Nothing looks odd to me.

As I said, the project run OK on Linux; OK on MSYS2 if no std::string.
In fact, not just std::string, std::vector cause error too.

Comment: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc0000135](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc0000135) is a missing dll

Comment: I knew 0xc0000135 is "DLL not found".  What I don't understand is why std::string cause this error ? Which DLL is missing ?
If I did not use std::string, everything is fine.

Comment: Use this program to figure that out: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: MSYS2 env ldd.exe and ntldd.exe both can be used to trace DLL dependencies.  So far, I think the problem should come from CTest ...

Comment: "ldd lib/test0.exe will display the DLL used. ctest -VV will display the PATH env. Nothing looks odd to me." - But the error is definitely about PATH. Whenever it *looks* odd for you or not. So, what **exactly** `ctest -VV` outputs for PATH variable? Add this output to the **question post**. Then, you may open a new terminal, assign PATH variable to exactly that value and try to run your `test0.exe`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more study, it's still not clear why `std::string` is causing the 0xc0000135 error. But I'm pretty sure `std::string` has nothing to do with the problem. It's purely a problem with CTest not being able to read `PATH` so it can't find the DLL.

There are three ways to solve this problem:

1. Add `WORKING_DIRECTORY` to `add_test()`, set it as the location of DLL:

```
add_test(NAME test0 COMMAND test0 WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

2. Using the `ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION` property, add the path of the DLL to PATH:

```
set_tests_properties(test0 PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION "PATH=path_list_prepend:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

3. This is also the root cause of the original error. When directly modifying the `ENVIRONMENT` property, the separator of `PATH` must be escaped by backslash !!

```
set_tests_properties(test0 PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib\\;$ENV{PATH}")
```